# Mongoid query has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a fairly simple mongodb model 
Currently 2 collections
Student
Courses (embeds Subjects)

```
class Student < User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :courses

class Course
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :student
  embeds_many :subjects
```

I know mongoid doesn't support querying has_many directly
i.e.

```
Student.courses
```

So if I wanted to get a students subject is this the only way

```
@student = Student.first
Course.find(@student.courses).subjects
```

This currently does 3 queries

```
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=test collection=users selector=    {"$query"=>{"_type"=>{"$in"=>["Student"]}}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (1.1775ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=test collection=courses selector={"student_id"=>"51f09457b5b605db25000002"} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.8862ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=test collection=courses selector={"_id"=>"51f09457b5b605db25000003"} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.8380ms)
```

Is there a more efficient way? 
I know I can embed Course in Student but I looking at also querying directly into Courses Collection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this.

```
Subject.where(:course_id.in => @student.courses.map(&:id))
```

Comment: Thats better. Trying to find documentation on .map function() know where that is?

Comment: From a query point of view doesn't seem to be any difference between using @student.courses and @student.courses.map(&:id))? Is there

Comment: Array#map is a standard Ruby method which iterates over an array, passes each value to the block, and collects the return values of the block into a new array.

Comment: Two lookups. One to find ids of all courses of a specific student. One to query to find subjects of those courses.